# How to give arguments in maven - for hadoop WordCount

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop, mapreduce

I am doing Hadoop `WordCount.java` in eclipse.

I am taking input and output path as an argument.

I am trying to convert my hadoop MR to maven from eclipse juno.

I wrote the pom.xml. But where should i include my parameter?

- `input:  /home/sree/myfiles/book.txt`
- `output: /home/sree/myfiles/wcout`

My edited `pom.xml`

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TryMaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>TryMaven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>

        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.WordCount</mainClass>

                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-Dinput=${input}</argument>
                        <argument>-Doutput=${output}</argument>
                        <mainClass>org.WordCount</mainClass>
                    </arguments>
                    <mainClass>org.WordCount</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: Parameters are text file and output folder for running wordcount in hadoop.

Comment: i will explain. i am working hadoop in cluster and eclipse. so while running in eclipse, i will be passing them as normal arguments ie runas->run configuration. and specify the arguments like this "/home/sree/myfiles/book.txt /home/sree/myfiles/wc"

Comment: I see that you've included the exec-maven-plugin, so that where you should add the arguments, see http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#arguments . If you run `mvn exec:java` I'd expect it to work.

Comment: Maven configuration is ok? Build is success after `mvn package`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven project is build tool, after migrating to maven you still can run your program as before. This is not maven related.

### Java solution

You can run WordCount without maven at all

```
java -jar target/TryMaven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dinput=/home/sree/myfiles/book.txt -Doutput=/home/sree/myfiles/wcout
```

### Maven solution

Changes to pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-Dinput=${input}</argument>
            <argument>-Doutput=${output}</argument>

            <argument>-classpath</argument>
            <classpath/>

            <mainClass>org.WordCount</mainClass>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Execute with command

```
mvn exec:exec -Dinput=/home/sree/myfiles/book.txt -Doutput=/home/sree/myfiles/wcout
```

**You can execute this goal directly from Eclipse!**

`Run as` -> `Maven bulid` and specify goal `exec:exec` with desired params

Comment: ok . but i am swithing my project to Maven. so i need to run that in eclipse without command line

Comment: i think u did nt get me...:( this pom.xml is fine. but it is running using commandline option right. but after setting pom.xml i need to run it from eclipse run as->Maven bulid

Comment: showing pasted the entire command in goal but getting:Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn".

Comment: remove `mvn` keyword, this is not needed. The goal is `exec:exec -Dinput=/home/sree/myfiles/book.txt -Doutput=/home/sree/myfiles/wcout`

Comment: normally i run as compile clean package exec:java ...this is not needed in goal?what is this goal "compile clean package exec:java' specifying?

Comment: showing :An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/sree/workspace/TryMaven/-Dinput=/home/sree/myfiles/book.txt but my path is correct.

Comment: It worked Mariusz but in a fault way.i jst build the maven and while executing the jar i gave the params : java -jar jarname input/path output/path